# System.Printing: need to listen for events

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, printing

I am developing a "windows service" for registering in our DB of printer events

Now I am reading documentation about [System.Printing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Printing%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) namespace. But for many of classes I see a little problem - as I can understand I must periodically call the "Refresh" method in order to know about changes in state of class instance. (E.g. [PrintQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Printing.PrintQueue%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class and its GetPrintJobInfoCollection and Refresh methods)

But I might prefer other approach - register some "listener" for some "event" instead of call "Refresh" every n milliseconds.

Please help me found documentation about events of System.Printing classes. Or, maybe, there is other library(assembly) with help of which I can implement the printer events monitoring

Comment: There are no events, it is a winapi restriction.  System.Printing does not help you implement this, you'll never get it reliable.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Well... I will look some other API...

Comment: Can you tell us about the progress ? I have the same issue

Comment: No, I used old approach: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15084/Printers-and-SafeHandles-Part?fid=330715&df=10000&mpp=10&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Expanded&spc=Relaxed&select=2213230&fr=11